# Android SQL Backup

Tags: android, backup, android-sqlite, android-backup-service

Is there any **Android Official** way of doing sql db backup to SD or Phone? there are several  backup helper classes mentioned in the document but all of 'em are pretty useless.

I know that the sql file is a simple db file i can use Java IO class to read and write somewhere. but that is not a wise idea if we have latest version of App which contains several  newly added columns in it. we cannot restore back.

Are there anyway to overcome this issue? Any easy way that so called android engineers provided in the document?

Comment: Did you think about serialization of data from DB you need? For example JSON as native android support.

Comment: I would like to go for DB only export not for xml or JSON. but if JSON works, how well?

Comment: You gotta export into something: XML, JSON, SQL or whatever else that can represent your structure of DB as well as values it contains. Simply query all data you need, go over cursor, read columns and write them into serialization format (eg JSON).

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Backup Manager?http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Here is an article on how to use it with Gson.

https://advancedweb.hu/2015/01/06/efficient-sqlite-backup-on-android/

Not sure if this is the best solution but this will allow you to pick and choose the columns you want to restore.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following approach:

1. make a copy of db file while back up.
2. Read that backup db file while restore using normal sqlite APIs.
3. Perform any operations like inserting default values for new columns if required and  insert    the data into the current db.You can perform the operations based on the version of db..The version of db can be encoded in the file name-something like backup_version_2.2.db
4. delete the backup db file